# Use other ssh key than id_rsa on heroku

Tags: heroku, ssh-keys

I have create a new ssh key for heroku wothout any passphrase. Than I deleted all other keys and added it to heroku using:

> heroku keys:add /Users/ME/.ssh/heroku.pub

but when I try to push new git changes I get the following popup:

[image]

Can anyone please tell why it asks password for "id_rsa"? It's a problem because I don't remember that password and I want to use another ssh key (`heroku` is this case).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a custom SSH key for Heroku deployment by editing your `~/.ssh/config` file.  This example assumes you have a private key named `heroku` that's located in `~/.ssh/`

```
Host heroku.com
  User git
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/heroku
```

Comment: When I first try to push changes to heroku, it asks which ssh key to use but I never choosed `id_rsa`. I don't know how or why but my problem solved by re-creating the `id_rsa` file as someone pointed out in another stackoverflow thread.